# Save and restore ad progress in Exoplayer IMA extension

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, imasdk

I'm trying to load a VAST ad using [Exoplayer IMA extension](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ima) (using tutorials [1](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ima), [2](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android)). I want to keep ad and content progress, so if app goes background or screen rotates, user continues from the point he/she was watching. You can see my code [here](https://github.com/Alireza-Farahani/Exoplayer-IMA-Test) and main codes below for convenience. (Duo to some limitations, I'm stuck with version 2.9.6 of Exoplayer library)

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;


    private static final String KEY_WINDOW = "window";
    private int currentWindow;
    private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";
    private long playbackPosition;
    private static final String KEY_AUTO_PLAY = "auto_play";
    private boolean playWhenReady;
    private ImaAdsLoader adsLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exo_video_view);
        if (adsLoader == null)
            adsLoader = new ImaAdsLoader(this, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.ad_tag_url)));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentWindow = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_WINDOW);
            playbackPosition = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_POSITION);
            playWhenReady = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_AUTO_PLAY, true);
        }
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory) {
        return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
    }

    private MediaSource buildAdMediaSource(MediaSource contentMediaSource, DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory){
        // Create the AdsMediaSource using the AdsLoader and the MediaSource.
        return new AdsMediaSource(contentMediaSource, dataSourceFactory, adsLoader, playerView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    private void initializePlayer() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        if (adsLoader != null)
            adsLoader.setPlayer(player);

        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.media_url_mp4));
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
        MediaSource contentMediaSource = buildMediaSource(contentUri, dataSourceFactory);
        MediaSource adMediaSource = buildAdMediaSource(contentMediaSource, dataSourceFactory);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        player.prepare(adMediaSource, false, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            initializePlayer();
            if (playerView != null) {
                playerView.onResume();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideSystemUi();
        if ((Util.SDK_INT < 24 || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer();
            if (playerView != null) {
                playerView.onResume();
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUi() {
        playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Util.SDK_INT < 24) {
            if (playerView != null) {
                playerView.onPause();
            }
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            if (playerView != null) {
                playerView.onPause();
            }
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseAdsLoader();
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            updateStartPosition();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
        if (adsLoader != null) {
            adsLoader.setPlayer(null);
        }
    }

    private void releaseAdsLoader() {
        if (adsLoader != null) {
            adsLoader.release();
            adsLoader = null;
            if (playerView.getOverlayFrameLayout() != null)
                playerView.getOverlayFrameLayout().removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        updateStartPosition();
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_AUTO_PLAY, playWhenReady);
        outState.putInt(KEY_WINDOW, currentWindow);
        outState.putLong(KEY_POSITION, playbackPosition);
    }

    private void updateStartPosition() {
        if (player != null) {
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            playbackPosition = Math.max(0, player.getContentPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, when screen rotates, activity fields like `ImaAdsLoader` becomes null and ad and content video play from start. I've saved player progress and can successfully restore it's position but that's not case for `ImaAdsLoader` since I couldn't find a way to restore its state. Am I doing anything wrong? How Ad progress state should be saved and restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern with video players is to prevent your activity from being recreated with orientation changes so you should add these flags to your manifest.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

This would also prevent the surface view that shows your video from being destroyed with orientation changes too.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution around IMA APIs, but none was given. Two approach came to my mind; the one you said and other one using ViewModel (or a similar approach). Since our codebase is a lagacy one, we ended up using your approach.

Answer (score 0):

The [README.md](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ima#readme) of the Exoplayer IMA extension is quite clear about this:
You need to persist a reference to the `ImaAdsLoader`. When recreating the view pass that reference back when `AdsLoaderProvider.getAdsLoader(MediaItem.AdsConfiguration adsConfiguration)` is called.

Additionally, persist the player position when the view gets destroyed by storing the value of `player.getContentPosition()`. After recreation seek that position before preparing the new player instance.

You can find an example in the Exoplayer's demo app's [PlayerActivity.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java).